# How to implement a Google ReCAPTCHA with dotenv?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, vite

im trying to implement the google's recaptcha when logging

Here's the Error: `process is not defined`

[image: process is not defined]

Heres my Code:

```
const key = process.env.REACT_APP_RECAPTCHA_KEY;
const [captcha, setCaptcha] = useState(false);

const onChange = (value) => {
  console.log("Captcha value:", value);
  setCaptcha(true);
}
```

```html
<OAuth />
<ReCAPTCHA
  sitekey={key}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
```

but unfortunately, the key is not being loaded from my dotenv file from the client folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lack some informations and is more subject about how to use **sensitive** env variable. I admit that ENV things can be confusing. I am speaking here only about how to access **sensitive environment variables** in your code:

You need to understand that `process.env` **is only** available **on server-side** and **not on the browser**, this is the reason you get an `undefined` error.

On local development environment, to test it, you could use:
`import.meta.env.REACT_APP_RECAPTCHA_KEY` instead of `process.env` *([documentation / informations](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html))* but pay attention to the following.

As you do not want your api-key to be publicly disclosed, you have two options to get it working in production:

- setup an **express server**: it will run from `nodejs` and will be able to use `process.env`
- add the key in the **configuration provided by the hosting provider**: you will  need to refer to their documentation, example there with [vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/environment-variables).

---

*Feel free to edit your post and asking for precisions, I will update the answer in consequence.*